# TSQL: List all users in all databases attached to an Azure SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I know I can go to each individual database and run:

```
SELECT name AS username FROM sys.sysusers
```

And that gets me a list of users for that Azure SQL Database.

And from the master DB on the Azure SQL Server, I can run:

```
SELECT name AS databasename FROM dbo.sysdatabases
```

But what I can't figure out for Azure is how to loop through all the databases and, for each database, list its users.

I obviously can't create a loop for USE @databasename since USE doesn't work for Azure SQL Databases.

The best I can do is write code to create code.  I looped through the databases and printed out a string to run sqlcmd for each database.  Obviously not ideal, but it was the best I could come up with.

Does anyone have any better suggestions for looping through all the Azure SQL Databases on an Azure SQL Server and running commands on each database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the case that you will need to iterate through each database to run your desired T-SQL but, I do have a query example that you might find useful.

Since you are looking to get a list of all users on a per database basis and not necessarily looking for `login` and `user` occurrences per database, this script will also provide you the *username* value as well as the *authenitcation_type* and *type* values pertaining to the method of authentication and the principal type of the user. This information is super beneficial as organizations move away from traditional SQL Login/User type accounts to managed directory principles and identity groups. This scenario may or may not apply in your case but I thought I would share:

```
select name as username,
   create_date,
   modify_date,
   type_desc as type,
   authentication_type_desc as authentication_type
from sys.database_principals
where type not in ('A', 'G', 'R')
   and sid is not null
order by username;
```

This example and additional information can be found on a blog authored by [Bart Gawrych[1](https://dataedo.com/@bart-gawrych) that is appropriately titled: [List users in Azure SQL database](https://dataedo.com/kb/query/azure-sql/list-users-in-database)

Note: His example excludes `Type = X` where I have modified this to include `External_User` or `External_Group` user *type* values....just for awareness.

Regards,
Mike